# Trouble Connecting Bluetooth Keyboard After updating and upgrading Raspbian

Tags: bluetooth, wireless, keyboard

I recently updated and upgraded my raspberry pi 3 b+, and now my Logitech keyboard K480 will not connect. It was working fine until this happened. I'm looking for any tips to see what I'm doing wrong/missing in terms of using the terminal to connect.

```
    pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo bluetoothctl 
    [NEW] Controller AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF raspberrypi [default] 
    [NEW] Device 11:22:33:44:55:66 Keyboard K480 
    [bluetooth]# agent on 
    Agent registered 
    [bluetooth]# default-agent 
    Default agent request successful 
    [bluetooth]# scan on 
    Discovery started 
    [CHG] Controller AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF Discovering: yes 
    [CHG] Device 11:22:33:44:55:66 RSSI: -66 
    [bluetooth]# pair 11:22:33:44:55:66 
    Attempting to pair with 11:22:33:44:55:66 Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists 
    [bluetooth]# trust 11:22:33:44:55:66 
    Changing 34:88:5D:A6:D7:E2 trust succeeded 

[bluetooth]# info 11:22:33:44:55:66 
Device 11:22:33:44:55:66    
Name: Keyboard K480     
Alias: Keyboard K480    
Class: 0x002540     
Icon: input-keyboard    
Paired: yes     
Trusted: yes    
Blocked: no     
Connected: no   
LegacyPairing: yes  
UUID: Service Discovery Serve.. (00001000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)  
UUID: Human Interface Device... (00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)  
UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)  Modalias: usb:v046DpB33Dd2803   
RSSI: -66 

[bluetooth]# connect 11:22:33:44:55:66 
Attempting to connect to 11:22:33:44:55:66 
[CHG] Device 11:22:33:44:55:66 Connected: yes 
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed 
[CHG] Device 11:22:33:44:55:66 Connected: no
```

So It's discovering, able to pair, able to trust, and able to creating a legacy pair, but it cannot connect due to an error described as org.bluez.Error.Failed.

in the GUI for bluetooth connection, like on the homescreen dock, the device is also discoverable but unable to connect, saying "Connection failed - GDBus.Error:bluez.Error.Failed: Input/output error".

I'm a total newb but I thought I could maybe get some hints from this site. The keyboard was working excellently before I updated/upgraded and tried out headless mode(ssh with Putty). Any help would be appreciated- I don't want to reflash raspbian but if I have to I will.

Comment: you have another error .... google `Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists `

Answer (score 2):

As jsotola mentioned, it looks like you are already bonded with the device and this is somehow getting in the way. My recommendation is to unbond before you scan & reconnect to the device. This can be done as follows:-

```
#bluetoothctl
[bluetoothctl] devices
[bluetoothctl] untrust 11:22:33:44:55:66
[bluetoothctl] remove 11:22:33:44:55:66
[bluetoothctl] scan on
[bluetoothctl] scan off
[bluetoothctl] connect 11:22:33:44:55:66
[bluetoothctl] pair 11:22:33:44:55:66
```

When you use 'scan on' make sure that you see your keyboard first before running 'scan off'.

I hope this helps.